# Gaming makes my CPU Temp & GPU Core Temp 85C+

Tags: 10.04, wine, games

Why playing Games in Ubuntu 10.04 using Wine makes my CPU Temp & GPU Core Temp 85C+ , also using flash player or browsing sites that use shock-wave flash plug in leads to the same problem "CPU Temp & GPU Core Temp 85C+". I tried to use Lightspark instead of flash player but it still has many bugs.

- Lenovo G550

  - Intel Core 2 Duo CPU 2.10GHZ
  - VGA : Nvidia GeForce G 105M
  - Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (64x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flash is CPU intensive because it can't use xv output. On your CPU model, a single page with a flash video (YouTube) should use about 25-35% of your CPU. Depending on the embedded flash player used by different sites, CPU usage can be higher than that.

Check my flash optimization tutorial for some tips:

http://firefox-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/05/flash-optimization.html

Comment: a single page with a flash video (YouTube) in full screen mode results in CPU Temp & GPU Core Temp 85C+ in just 4~10 minutes. i think i will try your "FlashVideoReplacer" ,Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Wine is CPU-intensive. If you open up your `System Monitor` and switch to the `Resources` tab, you will see that one of the cores is used up entirely. That is especially true of games like Counter-Strike:Source and similar.

Flash should not take up much CPU, and hence should not produce much heat. Though, of course, having many sites open with flashy Flash in them is a bad idea - it all adds up, small or not.

You can try to get the GPU temperature down by using NVidia's proprietary drivers, as it does some fan control and is generally more efficient than the nouveau driver shipped in Ubuntu by default.

And seeing that it is a laptop, both GPU and CPU temperatures can be beaten down with proper air circulation - make sure there's a lot of space under the laptop, or use a fan stand.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,actually any windows games even if its a tiny game like "super Mario " or "farm frenzy " ^^ eat up my CPU and playing one of those games for just 5 minutes is enough to make my laptop explode. about Flash, a single youtube video in full screen mode leads to the same overheat problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Check my flash optimization tutorial for some tips:
>
> http://firefox-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/05/flash-optimization.html

Thank you lovinglinux for your flash optimization tutorial. Worked just great for me. I edited my xorg.conf in **Maverick**, rebooted and logged in into Gnome without any problems. Now my cpu reaches much lower temperatures.

Would vote you up, pity I still don't have enough reputation. Promise I'll be back when I do.